# Show Convex Hull Collision in the viewport

Tags: 3d-view, collision, rigidbody

Like in the title, is there any way I can see the Convex Hull mesh when I enable the rigid body on an object? I can see sphere, box, cone and all the primitives, but convex hull nada. Seems like quite a needed feature to be able to see it, Maya has it for example.

I read somewhere a guy said "turn on view physics" but I searched everywhere and can't find it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

At the time of writing, displaying the Convex Hull collision boundary using the **Rigid Body > Collisions > Shape** setting does not seem to be possible (directly) - you have not overlooked an option.  However, recent activity on the developer.blender.org tracker indicates that this is being addressed.

Commits to the tracker have been put forward by Soumya Pochiraju, most recently less than a month ago so I would not be surprised to see this feature working sooner rather than later.  Whether this would come to Blender 2.93.x, 3.x or both, I don't know.

You can follow the current development commits using the following links:

- [Physics: enabled drawing for convex hull collision shape and corrected scale of compound child shapes](https://developer.blender.org/rB16cddb290e28cb1c14b52985207f38600f7b6f9d)
- [Physics: Implemented drawing convex hull collisions shapes using mesh_batch_cache functions](https://developer.blender.org/rB3c14b78dacc757cfba022aecc10c656fddcdb514)
- [Fix memory error in function for storing convex hull collision shape mesh data.](https://developer.blender.org/rB012445eb140caa6031b4f6fcec922a0a8defb50f)

In the meantime, you can also visualize your convex hull by using the **Add > Geometry > Convex Hull** node in the Geometry Nodes panel of Blender 3.0 Alpha.

[image: Mesh with Convex Hull geometry node applied]

Comment: Wow. That's what I call a comprehensive answer! :)